# How do you pass an optional command line argument for C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to write a program that will count the number of different possible passwords using the digits 0 - 9 under certain constraints. It's to have one required command line argument, which will be the number of digits in the password, while also having an *optional* argument, which will be the prohibited digit. No argument inputted will mean that all digits are allowed.

For example, should my program be called combinations:

```
$ combinations 8 3    #find number of passwords of length 8 with '3' not allowed
```

I tried looking it up and found that you can make an argument optional to a function with

```
int myfunction( int optional = 3);
```

for example. However that seems to set the value to a default value should nothing is input. I need it to allow all digits if it's left blank. How would I do it for command line arguments as well?

Comment: You can get the total no of arguments passed to the program by using `argc`. This counter gives the arguments including the file name. So, in the example given your `argc` will be 3. and you can build the rest of the logic around that.

Comment: If you're using `int myfunction( int optional = 3);` you're not writing C; only C++ allows default arguments.  However, that's not germane to the command line argument parsing.  Basically, you'll look at `argc` in `main()` and decide `argc == 2` means 'just the length' and `argc == 3` means 'length and forbidden digit'.  Anything else will be rejected with a usage message (`fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s length [forbidden]\n", argv[0]);` or thereabouts).  You'll also check that the arguments are valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Command line arguments are passed from the command line into your program as parameters to your `main` function. The signature of which needs to be `int main(int argc, char** argv)`.

The **second** parameter is an array of null terminated strings which hold every argument passed in the invocation of the program (including the name of the program). The first is is how many strings are in the array.

You will need to check that `argc > 2` and then parse `argv[2]` for the digit.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` is also acceptable.

Comment: @DavidBowling, yes but it's more syntactic sugar than an alternate form.